# Cross-platform web browser which allows to sync saved pages across devices

Tags: android, web-browser, synchronization

The phone runs on Android 2.3.4 and seems to run out of storage rather quickly. I have to reset it to factory defaults every month or so.

I tend to save a lot of important web pages for offline view, which is one of the reasons for the storage running low.

So far, Opera Mini only allows me to sync bookmarks. Would be really helpful if I could somehow sync the pages as well.

Comment: Do you want to sync open browser tabs or sync the actual content of those tabs?  What would be the benefit of syncing the actual content of the tabs vs directly accessing the pages?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - I can think of 2 benefits 1/ Cost especially on mobile devices & 2/ Save before going into locations with little or no signal.

Comment: Give Maxthon a try http://www.maxthon.com/

Comment: Only few [web browsers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser) support such an old Android version: Firefox is available cross-platform, and has Pocket integration (you could also use the Pocket addon if you prefer) for offline reading. But it is only available for Android 3.0 and above (Maxthon requires 2.2+). Maybe time to upgrade/replace the device (or install a custom ROM with a newer Android version)?

Comment: @Izzy - I've started using Pocket and it does the job, almost. It tends to change the web pages to a kind of read format which can be quite annoying if I have to see the full content of the web page without any kind of compression. I will try Maxthon. Or maybe just get a new phone.

Answer (score 1):

[Instapaper](https://www.instapaper.com/) is a web service and not a web browser, but it allows you to save webpages for offline viewing and store them on your Instapaper account. There's also an app for mobile devices.

Comment: I used Instapaper once. But it seems to save only the text and not the whole web page.